# Finding brakets within string VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I wish to make a Decoder for Virtual Piano, which will take the sheet Music from here(http://virtualpiano.net/category/music-sheets/) and convert it to a script for auto Hotkey. But i've run in a problem with detecting when the notes should be played at the same time, 
EXAMPLE 
If i was to input

G ou [pT] [OT]

it should come out as

```
Send G
Sleep, 100
Sleep, 100
Send o
Sleep, 100
Send u
Sleep, 100
Sleep, 100
Send p
Send T
Sleep, 100
Send O
Send T
Sleep, 100
```

But it comes out as

```
Send G
Sleep, 100
Sleep, 100
Send o
Sleep, 100
Send u
Sleep, 100
Sleep, 100
Send p
Sleep, 100
Send T
Sleep, 100
Send O
Sleep, 100
Send T
Sleep, 100
```

I wish to Find where "[" is and "]" then change the text In-between it
I Figered it out her it is

```
    start = TextBox1.Text
    Arraycounter = 0
    Do Until -1 = start.IndexOf("[")
        Front = start.IndexOf("[")
        Back = start.IndexOf("]")
        counter = Front
        Do Until counter = Back + 1
            Middle = Middle & start(counter)
            counter += 1
        Loop
        counter = 0
        MsgBox(Front & " - " & Back & " - " & Middle)
        start = Replace(start, Middle, SymbleArray(Arraycounter))
        Middle = Replace(Middle, "[", "")
        Middle = Replace(Middle, "]", "")
        Do Until counter = Middle.Length
            outp = outp & Replace(Middle(counter), Middle(counter), "SEND " & Middle(counter) & vbNewLine)
            counter += 1
        Loop
        MsgBox(outp)
        BraketArray(Arraycounter) = outp
        Arraycounter += 1
        Middle = ""
        outp = ""
    Loop
        Arraycounter = 0
    Do Until Arraycounter = 11
        start = Replace(start, SymbleArray(Arraycounter), BraketArray(Arraycounter))
        Arraycounter += 1
    Loop
    TextBox2.Text = start
End Sub
```

Comment: Please tell me if i need to be clearer as i'm not god at typing stuff up , if you want to see my full code just ask

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: I think you should process each character instead of using replace function.

Comment: ok i have posted my full code i've nearly got it all there i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to simplify your code. Put this code in a blank console project. Or if you want to use WinForm, change the Console.WriteLine("some string") to a textbox, eg. Textbox2.Text = "some string".

```
Dim input = "G ou [pT][OT]"

Dim foundBracket As Boolean

For Each c In input
    Select Case c
        Case " "
            Console.WriteLine("Sleep, 200")
        Case "["
            foundBracket = True
        Case "]"
            Console.WriteLine("Sleep, 100")
            foundBracket = False
        Case Else
            Console.WriteLine("Send {0}", c)
            If Not foundBracket Then Console.WriteLine("Sleep, 100")
    End Select
Next
```

I removed the space between ][ to match the expected result. I also use Sleep, 200 for spaces. If you need to handle some special symbols, just add them in the case statement.

Result of the code:

```
Send G
Sleep, 100
Sleep, 200
Send o
Sleep, 100
Send u
Sleep, 100
Sleep, 200
Send p
Send T
Sleep, 100
Send O
Send T
Sleep, 100
```

Comment: welp thats one way to shorten the code i just figerd it out myself but dam thats short, and this will be my last thing i'm able to ask becuse i'm already had one question with a -1 thing

Comment: so how would i use this in a normal form? i'm kinda lost sorry

Comment: In a winform? Set input from the input textbox, then change the Console.WriteLine to a textbox like I wrote in my answer.

Comment: Dim input = "G ou [pT][OT]" is changed to Dim input = Textbox1.Text

Comment: Console.WriteLine("Sleep, 200") is changed to Textbox2.Text = "Sleep, 200"